# export git blame to PDF or HTML

Tags: git, pdf-generation, git-blame

Is there a programmatic way to export `git blame` from a (text) file to either *PDF* (preferred) or *HTML*?

I know that github already offers a blame view in webbrowser (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/github/docs/blame/main/README.md)), but in the end I want to do a blame-export for all files in a given repository.

Comment: `git blame` (especially in conjunction with the `-p` switch) produces text output that can be easily parsed and converted to simple HTML files using simple shell scripts (or `awk`, `python`, `perl`, etc) or `pandoc` (for PDF files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since git doesn't offer that itself I ended up with @terrorrussia-keeps-killing [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69391726/export-git-blame-to-pdf-or-html#comment122649752_69391726) and wrote a python script:

1. run `git blame --line-porcelain <sha1> -- <fname>`
2. parse the output
3. generate HTML with jinja2 (see e.g. [this tutorial](https://realpython.com/primer-on-jinja-templating/)) and save to .html file

(the source is copyright-